# Get AWS Amplify react apps IP address for configuring a whitelist on API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I have react app which front end is hosted on Amplify, and Im using API Gateway for redirecting api calls to Lambda. I want to create a whitelist on api gateway but I cannot find the Amplifys IP address anywhere. I am not using VPC or Subnets (because its a simple app and didnt want to complex it by using vpc and subnets), the services are directly running on Amazon Cloud.

So my intention is to whitelist access coming only from Amplify and decline the rest.

I appreciate if anyone with ideas care to share.

Ive tried on accessing the IP from every aspect but no luck. Since there are no VPC or subnet I cannot whitelist their IPs and move on. If you have an idea please share :)